# need to generate the textbox and remove button dynamically

Tags: c#

### When i click add button i need to have textbox and its remove  button.finally when i click on dynamically generated remove button,

it   must remove its corresponding Textbox and button itself in asp.net c#  ##

```
  `     <div id="TextBoxContainer">
              <asp:panel ID="panel1" runat="server">  </asp:panel>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>

       =========================this is Aspx page which include Master 
        Page==========

         ************Now Aspx.cs (Code Behind) Page)Code********************


public partial class AddControl : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       public static int buttonclick = 0;
   protected void btnSubmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           buttonclick++;
           int count = buttonclick;
        int Total = Convert.ToInt32(count.ToString());
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < Total; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = i.ToString();
            panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Remove";
            btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(btn_Click); 
            panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            j++;
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide a text box and show a button?

Comment: No..I want to each time button is clicked generate a textbox with remove button

Comment: So what is not working right now? Please post the error if you get any errors

Comment: Problem is that when i click on button it generate textbox with remove button same as second time click it also generate ..But when we click on any textbox remove button , it remove all of generated textbox and again when i click on btnSubmt it generate all remove textbox include one extra textbox

Comment: You said, when you click on any text box, it removes all the text boxes and buttons?

Comment: when I click on any text box which is include remove button, it removes all the text boxes and buttons ....and again when i click to generate textbox it get the removed all textbox inlude one extra textbox

Comment: Are you there Buddy ???

Answer (score 0):

You're utilizing web-form's.  Which will make this quite tedious.  The reason, because the server will render your content, but unless every single "Add" or "Remove" for the textbox can perform a postback while tracking the provided textbox collection, this will create a clunky and even disconnected interface.

The route I would recommend, full client-side code and render a JavaScript template to insert your code.

```
<div>
     <input type="button" onclick="createField();">Create</input>
     <div data-rel="template-container">
          <input type="text" data-rel="appended-field" />
          <input type="button" onclick="removeField(this)">Button</input>
     </div>

     <input type="button" onclick="submitTextbox();">Submit</input>
</div>

<script id="dynamic-textbox" type="text/template">
     <div data-rel="template-container">
          <input type="text" data-rel="appended-field" />
          <input type="button" onclick="removeField(this)">Button</input>
     <div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function createField() {
          var template = $('#dynamic-textbox').html();
          $('[data-rel="template-container"]').append(template);
     }

     function removeField(element) {
         element.parent('[data-rel="template-container"]').toggle();
     }

     function submitTextbox() {
         var textboxes = $('[data-rel="appended-field"]).val();
         // Push to web-service, and save to database.
     }
</script>
```

The reason you would push to a web-service, because if web-forms doesn't do a postback and have you manually create the textbox from code behind, then it won't attach it to the form.

This approach will keep a layer of abstraction between code behind and front-end.  Which a front-end developer will appreciate when you're working with them.

Comment: I need to create in Web Form this is the requirement of client and no use any javascript or jquery. where my Web forms includes Master Page

Comment: @Amit Your client isn't allowing any JavaScript?  So they want the ugly, horrible, postback's?  Also, since you're attempting to be dynamic, you have to track the quantity of those fields and create them from code behind.  This will get overwhelming incredibly quick, you're aware of that?

Comment: There have no any quantity , Every time if button is clicked  it generate textbox with remove button

Comment: @Amit Unless you loop through every control, how do you assert a unique identifier to your dynamic control?  Otherwise you will have a random identifier for each one, or one control that could be affected by multiple.

Comment: @Amit I was writing the code, but the fact that you seem to not be trying is making me potentially not finish.

Comment: Ok...Thanks but if u have any solution then suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements negate JavaScript, you could do it in the following manner:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="upContent" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Button id="btnCreateTextbox" runat="server" onclick="btnCreateTextbox_Click" Text="Create"></asp:Button>
          <asp:Repeater id="rpFormField" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox id='<% Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:LinkButton id='btnDelete' runat="server" onclick='btnRemoveField_Click' CommandArgument='<% Eval(Name) %>'>Remove Field</LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void btnCreateTextbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int counter = 1;
     foreach(RepeaterItem item in rptFormField.Items)
     {
          var collection = new List<string>();
          Textbox textbox = (Textbox)item.FindControl("txtField");
          while(textbox != null)
          {
              collection.Add(textbox.Id);
              textbox = (Textbox)item.FindControl($"txtField-{counter}");
              counter++;
          }

          collection.Add($"txtField-{counter}");

          rpFormField.DataSource = collection;
          rpFormField.DataBind();
     } 
}

protected void btnRemoveField_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var collection = new List<string>();
     foreach(RepeaterItem item in rptFormField.Items)
          collection.Add(item.Id);

     string item = ((LinkButton)e).CommandArgument;
     collection.Remove(item);

     rpFormField.DataSource = collection;
     rpFormField.DataBind();
}
```

The code may have some errors, since I didn't validate it.  In particular the `Eval("Name")` area.  Plus, you'll need to actually setup the initial content / databind in page load and ensure that `!Postback` logic exist as well. Assuming that is all completed the code is straight forward.

Every time you hit the create button or delete, it will in essence repopulate the repeater to bind the content to the page.

Comment: That Get Error...in Many Places

Comment: I said I didn't do the entire code for you, you'll have to validate and tweak it a little bit.  I'm not going to do all your work.

Comment: Ya...I m saying to you that gettin Error....in that line which is              
        id='<% Eval("Name") %>'  and                                                   
 textbox = (Textbox)item.FindControl($"txtField-{counter}"); and         
  var item = ((LinkButton)e).CommandArguement;
     collection.Remove(item);

Comment: Error 101 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArguement' and no extension method 'CommandArguement' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)        Error 102 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Remove(string)' has some invalid arguments                                                                               Error 103 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' to 'string'

Comment: I fixed it in code, it should of all stemmed from misspelling `CommandArgument`, this is pretty easy stuff to figure out Amit, are you even trying to learn?

Comment: Sir, I always check Spell and correct them and it get no any option for CommandArgument value

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am done it using another code...and get some Logic from your Code....Thanks for your Help......

Answer (score 0):

```
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => 
        key.Contains("txtDynamic")).ToList();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            this.CreateTextBox("Dynamic" + i);
            i++;
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnDefault_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = plc.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count + 1;
        this.CreateTextBox("Dynamic" + index);
        btnValue.Visible = true;
    }

    private void CreateTextBox(string id)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + id;
        plc.Controls.Add(txt);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "btn" + id;
        btn.Text = "Remove";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(dynamicButton_Click);
        plc.Controls.Add(btn);

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        plc.Controls.Add(lt);
    }

    protected void dynamicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        string id = button.ID;
        string controlID = id.Substring(10, id.Length - 10);
        Control ctlTextbox = plc.FindControl("txtDynamic" + controlID);
        plc.Controls.Remove(ctlTextbox);

        Control ctlButton = plc.FindControl("btnDynamic" + controlID);
        plc.Controls.Remove(ctlButton);
    }

    protected void btnValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "";
        foreach (TextBox textBox in plc.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
                message += textBox.ID + " : " + textBox.Text + "<br>";
        }
        lblMessage.Text = message;
    }


}
```